# Tomcat reason phrase

Tags: http, tomcat

I've recently updated to Tomcat 9.0.0.M20 and noticed that Tomcat doesn't add a reason phrase to the status line of the http response.

Even if I use `HttpServletResponse.sendError(code, msg)`,  "msg" is not added to the status line, only html page generated my message.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. As of Tomcat 9, Tomcat no longer sends the reason phrase. Tomcat 8.5.x doesn't send the reason phrase by default but can be configured to do so. Tomcat 8.0.x and earlier will send the reason phrase.